# Come tradurreste "portable"?

Tags: translation

Per *portable computer* non c'è dubbio: *computer portatile*, ma tradurre *portable installation* con *installazione portatile* mi suona male, cosa potrei usare in alternativa?

*Installazione portabile* è corretto?

Un paio di frasi di esempio:

*To run ABC using this portable installation, you need to add the
appropriate binary directory to the search path...*

*The option XYZ installs for portable use on, e.g., a USB stick.*

Il senso di *portable* più vicino a ciò che sto cercando è *standalone*: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_application

Comment: Perché ti suona male?

Comment: _Installazione portabile_ è corretto. Potrebbe esserlo anche _installazione trasferibile_, ma sarebbe utile conoscere l'intera frase per capire meglio.

Comment: @DaG Non so, sarà perché non posso prendere un'installazione e portarla via :)

Comment: In linguaggio informatico, “porting a program” significa, per esempio, tradurre un programma scritto in un linguaggio in un altro (da Pascal a C) oppure adeguare un programma per un sistema operativo a un altro.

Comment: Puoi chiarire anche per gli ignoranti in che senso viene usato qui *portable* e perché sarebbe portabile ma non portatile?

Comment: @DaG Ho inserito un paio di frasi di esempio.

Comment: https://www.linguee.com/english-italian/search?source=auto&query=portable+installation viene usato nel link http://www.eazel.com/lv/group/view/kl80568/Identity_Cloaker.htm come traduzione di quest altro http://english.eazel.com/lv/group/view/kl80568/Identity_Cloaker.htm . A mio parere suona perfetto e l uso anche

Comment: Perdonami, @CarLaTeX, puoi definire (o dare un link a una definizione di) *portable* nel senso in cui ti serve? È “able to be transferred from one machine or system to another”? Io continuo a non capire, visto che sia “[portatile](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/portatile)” che “[portabile](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/portabile)” significano entrambi, di base, “che si può portare”, perché il primo non vada bene e il secondo sì. Tra l'altro, per “portatile” il Treccani dà anche “che non necessita di una installazione fissa”, che sembra simile al senso informatico.

Comment: @DaG Qualcosa simile a _standalone_, guarda l'ultimo aggiornamento della mia domanda.

Comment: Grazie, CarLaTeX. Quindi è qualcosa appunto di molto simile a “che non necessita di una installazione fissa”, che la Treccani dice di “portatile”. Che cos'ha quindi “portabile” di diverso da “portatile” oltre che un'assonanza con la parola inglese? Sarò di coccio, scusami.

Comment: @DaG Probabilmente è solo una mia impressione ma portatile mi dà più l'idea di qualcosa di fisico, come computer _portatile_

Answer (score 4, accepted):

La definizione corretta non credo sia "applicazione portatile" ma "[**applicazione portabile**](https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Applicazione_portabile)". Alcuni software (come ad esempio [FreeOffice](http://www.freeoffice.com/it/consigli-e-trucchi-installazione-mobile)) utilizzano l'espressione "**applicazione mobile**", che se però letta come se "mobile" fosse una parola inglese, potrebbe creare confusione e far pensare che ci si riferisca a software per dispositivi mobili.

Comment: Grazie per aver fornito una fonte che usa _portabile_! Cercando su internet ho trovato anche il contrario: https://www.aranzulla.it/come-creare-applicazioni-portatili-per-chiavette-usb-12855.html (tra l'altro ne approfitto per fare i complimenti a Salvatore Aranzulla, che scrivere sempre articoli utilissimi). A questo punto mi sa che si possono usare entrambi i modi.

Comment: Be', la Wikipedia non è una fonte in sé: riporta (o dovrebbe) le fonti di tutto quello che vi compare. (E Aranzulla [meglio lasciarlo perdere](https://www.google.it/amp/milano.repubblica.it/cronaca/2017/05/10/news/milano_immigrazione_salvatore_aranzulla_facebook-165085505/amp/)...)

Comment: @DaG Io mi riferivo agli articoli che scrive parlando di informatica, non ai sui post su FB, ovviamente.

Answer (score 3):

Io mi servirei di una perifrasi, supponendo che con il concetto di installazione portatile tu intenda una versione live di un software, direi "programma pronto all'uso". Se intendi invece un programma di installazione che puoi trasferire da un supporto all'altro, direi che si può usare direttamente "l'eseguibile".

Comment: Buona idea ma è un'installazione formata da vari componenti.

Comment: Ma si parla di software o no?

Comment: Sì, è un pacchetto completo che comprende programmi, documentazione, un editor, ecc.

Comment: Gli unici aggettivi che mi vengono in mente sono "trasportabile" o "trasferibile" ma mi sovviene un dubbio, nel senso installazione portatile è una specie di espressione ridondante, nel senso non esistono che io sappia "installazioni non portatili", quindi tanto vale dire solo "pacchetto di installazione"

Comment: Credo che nel caso del software in oggetto si intenda che è "_portable_" nel senso che non è necessario installarlo; basta decomprimerlo in una directory e lanciare l'eseguibile. In questo caso penso che la traduzione corretta sia "trasportabile" .

Comment: @RiccardoDeContardi Guarda gli esempi che ho aggiunto alla domanda, grazie!

Comment: Secondo me "portabile" va bene: "_L'opzione XYZ esegue l'installazione per un utilizzo portabile, per es. su una chiavetta USB_"

Comment: @mintrudemintrude Mi dispiace aver rifiutato il tuo edit (vedo che sei nuovo su Stack Exchange), ma cambiava troppo la risposta dell'autore, senza che vi fosse effettivo miglioramento, a mio parere. Le questioni di stile sono soggettive, e non è opportuno intervenire con cambiamenti quando il post è firmato da un'altra persona, che compare come autore e potrebbe non essere d'accordo. Soprattutto a tale distanza di tempo, per cui è probabile che l'autore non veda l'edit.